# Can't get Graphics to work on HP Pavilion G6

Tags: 12.04, graphics, ati, android, drivers

I have this crappy HP Pavilion G6 laptop (no other choice, provided by office) which is having troubles dealing with graphics (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

**Details of the machine:**
Its having a ATI Radeon graphics card, and I feel it is the main culprit.

I also had troubles installing it and only after following [this link](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/), I could install it.
(setting `nomodeset` in GRUB)

Now startup works good, but many things related to graphics don't.
(I installed Cinnamon too, but it also doesn't seem to work correctly)
I have all the updates applied.

I am currently facing problems in starting Android emulator to test my Android apps.
Whenever I try to start the emulator, I get following error message:

`Starting emulator for AVD 'Phone_41'

X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)

  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)

  Serial number of failed request:  12

  Current serial number in output stream:  12`

Apart from this, many other graphic related things do not work (Window switcher in graphic mode, Cinnamon)

If I head to `Settings>Drivers` I see two graphics drivers for the card being displayed:

[image]

The `post-release-updates` don't get installed and mess with the other one too (the one which is showing that it requires a restart)

**Problems:**

- Graphic Drivers can't be installed
- Android Emulator doesn't start, throws the above errors (maybe because of the graphics)

Is it a known issue or is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Im having trouble undertsanding what your bottom-line question is here.  Is it to fix your graphics or having the ability to start Android Emulator?  Please consider editing you question to be more specific.  As a starting point, the fact that you are suing 12.04, I think the instructions you used to install your ATI drivers are out dated.  Have a look at this Q&A http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513

Comment: Sorry for creating the confusion, I have edited the question, I hope its less confusing now. I am going through that link. Will I have to reinstall 12.04 all over again for the drivers?

Comment: No you dont have to reinstall 12.04 all over again but you may have to purge your current ATI driver installation.  In the link you are looking In the question stem there is link to an older question, the instructions for purging are there, good luck

Comment: Good, Lord!  I am just going to do what it says. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You can't install the post-release-update driver now.  It's a bug and will be fixed sonner or later.

Answer (score 1):

First things first Your **Graphics Card**

The link presented in your question contains outdated instructions to correctly install ATI graphics drivers for 12.04.  You need to purge this installation and reinstall the coorect graphics driver (ensuring you all meet all the correct dependencies).  This may also be the cause of Cinnamon not working (but if it il doesnt work you can ask a new question here).

Hopefully some else has knowledge about the Android Emulator (not a strong subject with me) but lets get you system stable first

Instructions on how to install your graphics driver [can be found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513)

Comment: I followed everything that you said on the link, and it still doesn't work :(  I feel this link: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide also says the same thing, but it just won't work. `fglrxinfo` says `Bad Request` and a few more errors and error codes. I have ATI Radeon HD 7450M card (found on HP website) and `sudo amdccle` pops up an error notification saying `AMD drivers are not installed`

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my Samsung laptop yesterday along with its Bumblebee driver for Nvidia card, and it all worked like a charm. But no success with this HP laptop :-/

Comment: I just recalled that I have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` set in `/etc/default/grub` Can this line be stopping the drivers to come into effect?

Comment: I tried removing `nomodeset` from grub during boot, and it again gives me a black screen after boot

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem.
I have:
  -Followed all the links.
  -Installed all the libraries.
  -Uninstalled/reinstalled, sudo aticonfig --initial=dual-head, ... nothing helpful.

My advice, although not very helpful, is to make a new installation on a computer that already has drivers available.  Build a computer with known working components that have the software to support it.  Otherwise I will keep my eye on this link for something USEFUL.

Comment: I have only this computer with me, and have no options but to use this one only for office purposes :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have to bother on certain systems when installing ATI graphics using Additional Drivers. To fix this, I open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Comment: for me, it says `fglrx is already the newest version`

Comment: I tried reinstalling it, and then received errors during boot that `your system is running in low graphic mode`. I repaired and switched back to the default version to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using HP pavillion g6-1302tx, i have followed the following link to install the graphic drivers on my laptop.

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-install-ati-amd-catalyst-122.html

Blank screen at the booting time is still an issue. Well setting nomodeset option abruptly increased the brightness of the screen and the brightness adjustment keys stopped responding; so it's better not to use nomodeset option.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: So if we don't use `nomodeset` then how else will that blank screen issue is resolved?

Comment: Surprisingly, I do get till the point where I am given this wizard, but then the wizard doesn't display any text. What I see is this: http://i.imgur.com/vVIPz.png

Comment: well I use the brightness keys for now.

Comment: Brightness is not a problem as of now. getting the drivers to work is. Did you see that image I posted above?

Comment: alright; i tried nomodeset at the time 12.04 was released; brightness was an issue then. Either the link i posted earlier or this http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513 might help you with the graphic drivers.  You have to install it manually, i guess.

Comment: Brightness is still an issue, and without `nomodeset` I can't boot (I get a blank black screen) and that link above, One of the answers is already about it; I have tried it but it didn't work, so.. :-/

Comment: i have the followed the link :- http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513; it worked fine for me. My graphic card is Raedon HD 6400.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4173/discussion-between-ankit-and-sheikh-aman)

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with the the same issue on my system (Though mine is a desktop) Go to the ATI website and grab the driver for "Linux" operating systems. It should come in a **.run** format once you have it on a thumb drive or wherever you need to do some very basic things (Which aren't so basic to find on the Internet). First Place the **.run** file on your desktop (For simplicity) then rename it something short, sweet, and to the point (EX. GD.run) which stands for (Graphics Driver). Then once you get to that point you need to shutdown "X" server before attempting to install. I assume you already know how to do this but in the case that you don't I will clarify because this is also not so straight forward on the Internet. So to shutdown "X" server you need to open terminal and run this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
```

sometimes that one fails to stop the "X" server so try this one. To check if it fails simply do the remainder of the steps and it will tell you whether the "X" server is still running.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

Then you need to press **CTRL+ALT+F1** and then enter the following. (Here comes the part why I told you to put it onto the desktop and name it something simple and easy to remember.)

```
Enter Login Credentials
cd ~/Desktop 
chmod +x GD.run
sudo ./gd.run
```

Then simply follow the steps given by the driver. Then to leave the black screen **CTRL+ALT+F7** After that point it is a matter of going to the Catalyst Manager and setting it up.

Comment: That really had set my hopes high ;-) I could install the drivers in command line mode and the driver was installed successfully. However, the black screen issue was still present (The laptop screen doesn't seem to be lit at all), for which I had to put `nomodeset` in grub to boot. but once the system boots up, it says its running in low graphics & I'll have to reconfigure the graphics, and somehow I can't go past that screen. Weird. Would you want any screenshot/video?

Comment: @Mathew any other suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You seems to have 2 problem at the same time:

- a problem with the drivers of your graphic card, in this case i suggest to take a look at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page which is a good place to start and remember to uninstall everything that is old before installing something new
- a problem with your android environment, and in this case you probably are messing up with the Mesa library that is the OpenGL implementation used by the Android emulator, just take a look at how to setup your OS for Android development http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: -1 Neither of these points are a solution to the issue presented there fore should be comments not answers.  You have just stated you understand the issues and provided links (which may or may not be useful) but you do not definitely state that these will fix these issues.  please edit and improve the quality of your answer.